# Improve Mechanical Switch Reliability

Tags: power-supply, relay

Currently I use a USB-6501 DIO and inexpensive Sansmart 8x1 SPDT relays to switch on/off numerous inexpensive fixed DC power supplies for a flash programming process. Every 20,000 to 50,000 parts i have to replace the relay board. Is there a better way to switch DC voltages and get higher switch reliability?

Comment: 1. By adding a snubber circuit on relay output, 2. Using solid state DC relay. There is no link of the used relays type, current/voltage ratings, ...etc

Comment: also on the relay coil circuit

Comment: I considered using a solid state relay but have been told that when these devices go bad they fail as a short. Mechanical relays fail as an open a big enough drop to affect the load.